# Expression Blend no longer has project templates

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

When trying to create a new project, there is nothing in the "New Project" dialog to choose from.
I will make the issue easy to understand with an image:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall / reinstall?

Comment: Is this the blend for tools version or the full version?

Comment: What did you install/uninstall prior to this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you uninstalled the Silverlight developer runtime?

The easiest thing to do may be to hit this link and run the web installer: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/